# GGPlot Axis Customisation (Space/Segmentation)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that I would like to segment into 'baseline' and '6-months'

- 6 months variables are labelled x1/x2
- baseline is self-titled.

I would like to customise the plot so that:

- there is separation/space between two subsets (baseline + six months)
- And potentially so that the two subsets have different bar widths.

Would appreciate any ideas on how to encode this in R and the types of packages used.

Thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

x1 = rep(1:3, times = 2)
x2 = rep(c("Y", "N"), each = 3)
baseline = rep(0:1, times = 3)
y <- data.frame(x1,x2,baseline)

Dat <- y |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "var")

ggplot(Dat, aes(y = var)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("x1")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "B", guide = guide_legend(order = 3))+ 
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("x2")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("baseline")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", guide = guide_legend(order = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to add some space between the two subsets and have a different bar widths would be to create two separate plots and glue them togther using e.g. `patchwork`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

x1 = rep(1:3, times = 2)
x2 = rep(c("Y", "N"), each = 3)
baseline = rep(0:1, times = 3)
y <- data.frame(x1,x2,baseline)

Dat <- y |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "var")

p1 <- ggplot(Dat, aes(x = var)) +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("x1")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "B", guide = guide_legend(order = 3))
  
p2 <- ggplot(Dat, aes(x = var)) +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("x2")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("baseline")), aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
  
library(patchwork)

p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again @Stefan, you're a real source of help. Is there anyway you could customise 'var' on the horizonal axis to, I dunno, var1 and var2, with a simple execution, or would that have to be customised under the pivot-longer commands?

Comment: Add `+ labs(x = "var1")` to the first plot and `+ labs(x = "var2")` to the second. Or `+ labs(x = NULL)` to remove the axis title. One drawback opf using pathcwork is that we can't have one axis title.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to make the 'x' axis numeric with custom labels and adjust the widths manually:

```r
ggplot(Dat, aes(y = 5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("x1")), width = 1,
           aes(fill = value), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "B", guide = guide_legend(order = 3)) + 
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("x2")), aes(fill = value, y = 6), 
           position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(.x, var %in% c("baseline")), width = 2,
           aes(fill = value, y = 1), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 5, 6), labels = c('Baseline', 'x1', 'x2'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Allan Cameron. That's a nice trick. Thanks for your help :) (I am also a Glaswegian who hates the rain).